# How do I make my absolute-positioned elements responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to center (horizontally & vertically) this circle of shapes in the middle of the container and make it responsive. I do not know how to keep the circular shape without absolute positioning. Any help is appreciated!

```js
var n = 20;

for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    var r = 360 * i / n;
    var s = 'translate(200px,200px) rotate(' + r + 'deg) translate(0px, -80px)';
    
    d.setAttribute('class', 'box');
    d.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:' + s);
  
    
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(d);
}
```

```css
.box {
    background: #d0d0d0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.box:hover {
     background: red;         
}
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ths432/6qtm28f5/52/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position them relatively to the container and then center the container:

```js
var n = 20;

for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  var r = 360 * i / n;
  var s = 'translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(' + r + 'deg) translate(0px, -80px)';

  d.setAttribute('class', 'box');
  d.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:' + s);


  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(d);
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  margin:100px auto; /* 80x + 20px */
  width:200px; /* 2*80px + 2*20px */
}

.box {
  background: #d0d0d0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* the below conmbined with the translate(-50%,-50%) in the JS will center */
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}

.box:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using border-radius of 50%, relative positioning rather than absolute, and margin: auto. This will force the box to the center of its container.

```
.box {
    background: #d0d0d0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
}
```

This css will create an ellipse rather than a circle, due to the different height and width attributes. If a circle is the behavior you were looking for, change heigh and width to have the same value.

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work. I am trying to center the circle of shapes as a whole.